# Visual studio start line by line debugging in the middle of a program

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am working on a program and a lot of the buttons and menu items are dynamically created. Its especially hard to work on because I don't know where they are created and assigned to. It would help  if I could start up the program via debugger, get to the menu, then switch to "line by line" style debugging like pressing F10, where the next line of code ran would break, and then press one of the buttons to get more info about it once the break happens. Is there any way I can do this in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you have the Solution Explorer. There you see the Project files, they are under the top level Solution. If you right click on your main project, go to: Debug > Step Into New Instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on a .NET application, you can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to see what code is executed when you select a menu item or press a button.

Answer (score 0):

The closest way I could figure out how to do this is to go into Debug>Disable All Breakpoints   and then when I get to where I need to be in the program go back and Enable All Breakpoints. Of course this only works if there is a large number of breakpoints in places in the program.